# About the series $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\mu(n)}n\,\left(\frac12-\{nx\}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, fourier-series

With the usual notation $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor,$ the fractional part of $x,$ we can calculate the Fourier series of the function $f(x)=\frac12-\{x\},$ a periodic function with period $1.$ The result is
$$f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{\pi n}\,\sin2\pi nx,\tag{1}$$ cf. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html.

Now let's remember Mobius inversion (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula): informally, we would obtain
$$\frac1\pi\,\sin2\pi x=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\mu(n)}n\,f(nx)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\mu(n)}n\,\left(\frac12-\{nx\}\right).\tag{2}$$

I emphasized "informally", because  the assumptions of the inversion formula aren't satisfied: the series in (1) is not absolutely convergent. Is (2) still true? Here's a plot of the RHS (summing up to $n=5000000$):[image]

So it seems to be true, but how to formally justify it? Fun fact: for $x=0,$ that would mean $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\mu(n)}n=0,\tag{3}$$ and that's true (while the RHS of (1) is $0\neq f(x)=\frac12$ for integer $x$). It is also equivalent to the prime number theorem.

Question: Is it possible to justify (2), with or without using (3)?

Comment: this is a highly non-trivial result of Davenport established (together with a few more similar but somewhat easier identities) in two very important papers https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/os-8/1/8/1564852?redirectedFrom=fulltext and https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/os-8/1/313/1564796?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: @Conrad Thank you, that's the information I was hoping for. So the series converges uniformly, but you need Vinogradov's estimates of exponential sums (like (1) in the second article you cited) to prove that. Very interesting!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: @Conrad You may want to post that in an answer.